# Javascript how to merge or combine array of days with same opening hours

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of days and the opening hours:

```
let arrData = [
{
  "dayOfTheWeek":"Monday",
  "isOpen":true,
  "hoursOfBusiness":[
     {
        "opensAt":"10:00:00",
        "closesAt":"15:00:00"
     }
  ]
},
{
  "dayOfTheWeek":"Tuesday",
  "isOpen":true,
  "hoursOfBusiness":[
     {
        "opensAt":"10:00:00",
        "closesAt":"15:00:00"
     }
  ]
},
{
  "dayOfTheWeek":"Wednesday",
  "isOpen":true,
  "hoursOfBusiness":[
     {
        "opensAt":"10:00:00",
        "closesAt":"15:00:00",
     }
  ]
},
{
  "dayOfTheWeek":"Thursday",
  "isOpen":true,
  "hoursOfBusiness":[
     {
        "opensAt":"09:00:00",
        "closesAt":"16:00:00",
     }
  ]
},
{
  "dayOfTheWeek":"Friday",
  "isOpen":true,
  "hoursOfBusiness":[
     {
        "opensAt":"10:00:00",
        "closesAt":"14:00:00",
     }
  ]
},
{
  "dayOfTheWeek":"Saturday",
  "isOpen":false,
  "hoursOfBusiness":[]
},
{
  "dayOfTheWeek":"Sunday",
  "isOpen":false,
  "hoursOfBusiness":[]
}
]
```

And I want to combine the days where the opening hours are the same. So, basically my goal is to display the opening hours like this:

```
Monday-Wednesday: 10-15
Thursday: 9-16
Friday: 10-14
```

So, I tried to to this:

```
function openingHours(data){
   let merged = [];
   let idx = -1;
   for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     let day = data[i];
     if (
       idx == -1 ||
       merged[idx].hoursOfBusiness.opensAt != day.hoursOfBusiness.opensAt
     ) {
      merged.push({
        days: day.dayOfTheWeek,
        opensAt: day.hoursOfBusiness.opensAt,
        closesAt: day.hoursOfBusiness.closesAt,
      });
     idx++;
    } else {
      merged[idx].days.push(day.dayOfTheWeek);
    }
  }
 return merged;
}
```

but this doesn't really work. I have created a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/on51c49b/13/) so please check it out.

Can someone help me out?

**UPDATE**

All answers were pretty useful but actually I need a different output after all, since the opening/closing hours can vary, I need something like:

```
data: [
   {
     days: "Monday-Wednesday",
     opensAt: "10:00",
     closesAt: "15:00
   },
   {
     days: "Thursday",
     opensAt: "09:00",
     closesAt: "16:00
   },
   {
     days: "Friday",
     opensAt: "10:00",
     closesAt: "14:00
   },
]
```

I hope someone could help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with the data/code

1. the `hoursOfBusiness` in the data is an array
2. the `hoursOfBusiness` in merged item is not available - u have directly added the opensAt property to it
3. Not all the items have data into it - `hoursOfBusiness` for saturday and sunday is empty array

Below is the updated code considering the data as you have provided, and also considering that in your merged object you don't need array

```
function openingHours(data){
  let merged = [];
  let idx = -1;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let day = data[i];
    if(day.hoursOfBusiness.length == 0){
    continue
    }
    if (
      idx == -1 ||
      merged[idx].opensAt != day.hoursOfBusiness[0].opensAt
    ) {
      merged.push({
        days: [day.dayOfTheWeek],
        opensAt: day.hoursOfBusiness[0].opensAt,
        closesAt: day.hoursOfBusiness[0].closesAt,
      });
      idx++;
    } else {
      merged[idx].days.push(day.dayOfTheWeek);
    }
  }
  return merged;
}

console.log(openingHours(arrData))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could first group days by `open-close` time inside one object and then modify that object to get the desired structure of `days: time`. This assumes that the input data is sorted by the correct days order otherwise you would have to add that sorting step.

```js
let data = [{"dayOfTheWeek":"Monday","isOpen":true,"hoursOfBusiness":[{"opensAt":"10:00:00","closesAt":"15:00:00"}]},{"dayOfTheWeek":"Tuesday","isOpen":true,"hoursOfBusiness":[{"opensAt":"10:00:00","closesAt":"15:00:00"}]},{"dayOfTheWeek":"Wednesday","isOpen":true,"hoursOfBusiness":[{"opensAt":"10:00:00","closesAt":"15:00:00"}]},{"dayOfTheWeek":"Thursday","isOpen":true,"hoursOfBusiness":[{"opensAt":"09:00:00","closesAt":"16:00:00"}]},{"dayOfTheWeek":"Friday","isOpen":true,"hoursOfBusiness":[{"opensAt":"10:00:00","closesAt":"14:00:00"}]},{"dayOfTheWeek":"Saturday","isOpen":false,"hoursOfBusiness":[]},{"dayOfTheWeek":"Sunday","isOpen":false,"hoursOfBusiness":[]}]

const parseTime = str => str.split(':').slice(0, 2).join(':')
const daysRange = arr => [arr[0], arr.length > 1 ? arr[arr.length - 1] : null].filter(Boolean)

const merged = data.reduce((r, {
  dayOfTheWeek,
  hoursOfBusiness: hours,
  isOpen
}) => {
  if (isOpen) {
    hours.forEach(({ opensAt, closesAt }) => {
      const time = `${opensAt}-${closesAt}`;
      if (!r[time]) r[time] = {
        days: [],
        opensAt: parseTime(opensAt),
        closesAt: parseTime(closesAt)
      }
      r[time].days.push(dayOfTheWeek)
    })
  }

  return r;
}, {})

const result = Object.entries(merged)
  .map(([_, value]) => ({ ...value,
    days: daysRange(value.days).join('-')
  }))


console.log(result)
```

Comment: Pretty cool! Unfortunately I need a different output than expected - please check my updated question...

Answer (score 0):

You have some error in your code: First `days` must be array not string and then in `else if` part you may need to check `day.isOpen`.

And finally use `map` to show array with your format

Here is working snippet:

```js
let arrData = [
    {
        "dayOfTheWeek": "Monday",
        "isOpen": true,
        "hoursOfBusiness": [
            {
                "opensAt": "10:00:00",
                "closesAt": "15:00:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dayOfTheWeek": "Tuesday",
        "isOpen": true,
        "hoursOfBusiness": [
            {
                "opensAt": "10:00:00",
                "closesAt": "15:00:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dayOfTheWeek": "Wednesday",
        "isOpen": true,
        "hoursOfBusiness": [
            {
                "opensAt": "10:00:00",
                "closesAt": "15:00:00",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dayOfTheWeek": "Thursday",
        "isOpen": true,
        "hoursOfBusiness": [
            {
                "opensAt": "09:00:00",
                "closesAt": "16:00:00",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dayOfTheWeek": "Friday",
        "isOpen": true,
        "hoursOfBusiness": [
            {
                "opensAt": "10:00:00",
                "closesAt": "14:00:00",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dayOfTheWeek": "Saturday",
        "isOpen": false,
        "hoursOfBusiness": []
    },
    {
        "dayOfTheWeek": "Sunday",
        "isOpen": false,
        "hoursOfBusiness": []
    }
]


function openingHours(data) {
    let merged = [];
    let idx = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let day = data[i];
        if (
            idx == -1 || (day.hoursOfBusiness.length > 0 && merged[idx].opensAt != day.hoursOfBusiness[0].opensAt)
        ) {
            merged.push({
                days: [day.dayOfTheWeek],
                opensAt: day.hoursOfBusiness[0].opensAt,
                closesAt: day.hoursOfBusiness[0].closesAt,
            });
            idx++;
        } else if (day.isOpen) {
            merged[idx].days.push(day.dayOfTheWeek);
        }
    }
    return merged;
}
let result = openingHours(arrData);

let normalizeResult = result.map(t =>
({
    days: t.days.length == 1 ? t.days[0] : (t.days[0] + "-" + t.days[t.days.length - 1]),
    opensAt: t.opensAt.split(':').slice(0, 2).join(':'),
    closesAt: t.closesAt.split(':').slice(0, 2).join(':')
})
); 

console.log(normalizeResult);
```

Comment: @ST80 Look at `result` variable in my code. You have all information you need so you can show in any way you want. I am going to update the answer to show updated result